# Is there a way to trigger postman tests remotely from HTTP

Tags: postman

We would like to have postman execute a set of health checks after deployment to an environment. We currently use VSTS to deploy our builds and want to trigger postman remotely via HTTP. If the health checks pass we want to return 200, if they fail then 500.

We currently use Postman pro and our tests are stored on postmans website.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with Postman.

You can alternatively use [Newman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman) on your environment which would execute the same requests/tests as Postman does. It can be integrated with e.g. Jenkins CI Server.

Comment: Thought about this option but that requires exporting our Postman json files and storing them in another git repo / CI system. Since we use postman pro and the files are hosted on their servers we would like to trigger remotely.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule collection runs using [Postman monitors](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/monitors/intro_monitors) - essentially running your collections (and associated tests) on Postman servers.

You can also use [Newman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/command_line_integration_with_newman) to integrate with your CI/CD pipeline. Here's a [tutorial  using VSTS with Newman](https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/04/postman-newman-vsts-continuous-integration/). This requires a 'local' collection and environment file, but you can use the [Postman API](https://docs.api.getpostman.com/) to programmatically get your latest Postman data.